# How do I resolve this Issue with rendering data table component with data retrieved from Java API?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting data from springboot java api using axios in React. The Bootstraptable2 is not rendering rows due to "Failed prop type: Invalid prop `row` of type `string` supplied to `Cell`, expected `object`.".

```
JSONArray result = new JSONArray();
ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();

Iterable<ContactCase> clist = cntCaseRepository.findAll();
for (ContactCase c_ind: clist)
{
   try {
   result.put(obj.writeValueAsString(c_ind));
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
return ""+result;
```

React code :

```
 type { cases: Array<Object> }

 this.state : { 
 cases:[]
 columns: {
    dataField: 'id',
    text: 'ID'
    }, {
    dataField: 'caseNumber',
    text: 'Case Number'
    }
 }

 componentDidMount() {
 axios.get(getUri).then((response) => {

  var newA = new Array(response.data);
  this.setState({ cases : newA })
 });
}

render()
{
return (<BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={ this.state.cases } columns={ 
 this.state.columns } /> )
}
```

Columns headers and empty rows equal to the no of records are rendered.

```
checkPropTypes.js:19 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `row` of type `string` supplied to `SimpleRow`, expected `object`.
    in SimpleRow (created by Body)
    in Body (created by BootstrapTable)
    in table (created by BootstrapTable)
    in div (created by BootstrapTable)
    in BootstrapTable (created by Context.Consumer)
    in SortProvider (created by Context.Consumer)
    in DataProvider (created by BootstrapTableContainer)
    in BootstrapTableContainer (at Previews.tsx:
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Body`. .
    in SimpleRow (created by Body)
    in Body (created by BootstrapTable)
    in table (created by BootstrapTable)
    in div (created by BootstrapTab
checkPropTypes.js:19 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `row` of type `string` supplied to `Cell`, expected `object`.
    in Cell (created by RowPureContent)
    in RowPureContent (created by SimpleRow)
    in tr (created by SimpleRow)
    in SimpleRow (created by Body)
    in tbody (created by Body)
    in Body (created by BootstrapTable)
    in table (created by BootstrapTable)
    in div (created by BootstrapTable)
```